# get form serialize data from submit button (from several forms)

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I can not get get the data to send by formdata , being a form no problem, but like many with the same class and not take them.

but always use these two do not work

```
$('.form').submit(function(){ 
    alert($(this).serialize());
});

$('.submitform').click( function(e) {
  var form=$(this.form);
  alert(form.serialize());
});
```

**EDIT**

this is the 3 example forms,
I need to get the value of the form is submitted by its class , but the 3 have the same class

```
<form action="page" class="formEnviar">
<input type='text' readonly value="1" class="form-control input-sm" name="de" />
<button type="submit" class="submitform" class="submitform btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>

<form action="page" class="formEnviar">
<input type='text' readonly value="2" class="form-control input-sm" name="de" />
<button type="submit" class="submitform" class="submitform btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>

<form action="page" class="formEnviar">
<input type='text' readonly value="3" class="form-control input-sm"  name="de" />
<button type="submit" class="submitform" class="submitform btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your actual form?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explain what you want to do and what is problem you are facing.

Comment: look the edit please.

Comment: you have button in each form. Do you want to get serialized data of all forms when one of them is clicked?

Comment: I want the form data of the submitted form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want too get serializea data of multiple forms.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
  alert($('.form').serialize());
  $('form').submit();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form" action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  
</form> 
  
<form class="form" action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
</form> 
<button id="btn" type="button">Submit</button>  
</body>
</html>
```